# I'm trying to loaded css,js and image in Laravel 5.7 but it's not working

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.7

Here is my Bootstrap links which I'm using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
```

and js

```
 <script src="{{ asset('js/vendor/jquery-1.12.0.min.js') }}"></script>
```

but both are not loaded in my template.

routes are below:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home', ["bodyClass" => ""]);   
});
```

Used of bodyClass also but not working(`<body class="bodyClass">`) in html code. Inside the body all needed (header, footer, banner and content) include. But can't run so.

Here is my website Link: http://ecodexpert.com/

Comment: Here is my site link: http://ecodexpert.com/

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: It loads fine. Does it work now?